# 強い風だから全然聞けなかった Translation Help

Tags: translation

> 強い風だから全然聞けなかった

Translation:

> Because Of The Strong Wind (I:Implied) Could Not Hear At All.

Is This Right?

Comment: It was a more interesting question before you edited it.

Comment: Indeed. It reminded me of 風の歌を聴け by Haruki Murakami. :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

In the real Japanese-speaking world, however, it would be more natural to say 「[聞]{き}こえなかった」 than to say 「聞けなかった」.